# Python/Django request.FILES['']

Tags: python, django, templates

I know this is easier than I'm making it... I want to get the data and filename for a

```
file = request.FILES['test']
```

Im going to be storing the image into a fire database. My question is, do I need up save the image to my python server before I can save it to the firebase DB? If I need to save it to the server db, then what is the correct way to do this? I was under the impression that I could just get the image data and pass that along to the firebase db.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Denis Angell

Comment: so do you want to save image from POST data and you don't want to save in django server?

Comment: I want to save the image from post data

Comment: You'll have to do it manually after you receive the POST data. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files